# Does a using block keep an object alive?

Tags: c#, using, object-lifetime

For some unit tests, I want to set the CurrentCulture to a particular culture (and then reverse these changes later). As I need to do this in several places, I was thinking of writing a CultureChanger class which saves the old culture and sets the new culture in its constructor, and then resets the old culture during its disposal.

Then I could use it like this:

```
using(new CultureChanger(culture)){  
    //some code and assertions with no references to the CultureChanger 
}
```

If I did this, is there a risk that the CultureChanger could get cleaned up sometime before the using block completes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CultureChanger` won't get cleaned up until after the `using` block "completes".

The `using` block defines the scope for the object in much the same way a method does.

There's no guarantee on *when* the object will be garbage collected after the block executes, but it won't happen before.

Comment: even with some awesome optimizations or what not? or rather - is the `using` statement *garanteed* not to dispose the object before the using completes?

Comment: And if you would like to have something executed specifically at the moment the block ends, have the class implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: @Default - even with awesome optimizations.

Comment: @RenéWolferink you can't use `using` on a class that doesn't implement `IDisposable` right?

Comment: Just a question, but you wrote "the same way a method does" but a method, stores a value usually in a variable, a parameter in that case, but its not available here. So we seem to have no root object, which object is holding the reference to CultureChanger?

Comment: @WouterH: Oops, you're right! However, the rest was still valid, anything you want executed at the end of the block, put it in the `Dispose` method. As it will be translated internally to a `try ... finally` block in which `Dispose` will be called.

Answer (score 1):

[using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) rovides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.

The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called. Within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object.

Answer (score 1):

The CultureChanger instance will stay "alive" throughout the using block and its Dispose method will be called on the closing curly brace '}' of the using statemnet. So the answer to you question is: There is no risk that the CultureChanger could get cleaned up.